# Limit number of tweets in Tumblr

Tags: tumblr

I'm using the twitter block in tumblr which displays the latest tweets from my twitter feed. Right now it displays the last 20 tweets but I want it to only show the last 5 tweets. anyone have any idea how I can do that?

the code I'm using right now is below. I tried changing the .length variable to 5 in the loop, but that didn't do anything:

```
 {block:Twitter}
    <div id="twitter" style="display:none;">
        <h3><a href="http://twitter.com/{TwitterUsername}">Latest Tweets</a></h3>

        <div id="tweets"></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function recent_tweets(data) {
            for (i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
                document.getElementById("tweets").innerHTML =
                    document.getElementById("tweets").innerHTML +
                    '<a href="http://twitter.com/{TwitterUsername}/status/' +
                    (data[i].id_str ? data[i].id_str : data[i].id) +
                    '"><div class="content">' + data[i].text +
                    '</div></a>';
            }
            document.getElementById("twitter").style.display = 'block';
        }
    </script>
{/block:Twitter}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how you changed the variable, but this should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function recent_tweets(data) {
        for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
            document.getElementById("tweets").innerHTML =
                document.getElementById("tweets").innerHTML +
                '<a href="http://twitter.com/{TwitterUsername}/status/' +
                (data[i].id_str ? data[i].id_str : data[i].id) +
                '"><div class="content">' + data[i].text +
                '</div></a>';
        }
        document.getElementById("twitter").style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>
```

### Update

You'll also need to remove the 2nd `recent_tweets` function that your are calling. The one you change to be `i<5` is being overwritten by another one being called later in your theme file.

Comment: I already tried to change the condition in the loop from "data.length" to "5" but that didn't work.

Comment: `for (i=0; i<5; i++)` will **only** go through five times, so I'm not sure what the problem is here. Did you copy/paste exactly what I posted above? Sometimes it takes Tumblr a little bit to update as well, so make sure you're not just refreshing immediately and saying it doesn't work.

Comment: @garygilmore I copied your code exactly. I've given tumblr an hour to digest but it's still showing the last 20 tweets

Comment: Do you have a link to your site?